# how to store a pressed key name from event in a Class Variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

so i'm creating an application with python 3.7(`windows`) and tkinter model
and i wanted to control some of the options in my app using key events 
( when the user press a specific key a specific action happen) sounds simple right !

so i tried to do that using a class contain variable and callback function

and the result was not as i expected , 
i was able to print the pressed key name directly **inside** the callback function
**BUT !!** what i wanted exactly is the to **store that key name in a `variable` to use it outside the class**

something like :

```
class keySystem:

pressedKey = None

def callback(event):
    keySystem.pressedKey = repr(event.char)


myWindow.bind("<Key>", keySystem.callback )
print( "the user have Pressed : ", keySystem.pressedKey )
```

**The Goal :** store which key name have been pressed from the event in my "class variable" (`pressedKey`) to use it outside the class

---

**# example of usage :**

```
if keySystem.pressedKey == "g":
    mySettings.open()
if keySystem.pressedKey == "Esc":
    mySettings.Exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you need to define it as a class variable and call it using class' object. The `__init__ function` helps in this case and do make sure to use the self keyword inside each function. I'll give a very simple example below:

```
class keySystem:

    def __init__(self):
        pressedKey = None

    def callback(self, event):
        self.pressedKey = event


object=keySystem()
object.callback('Enter')
print( "pressed : ", object.pressedKey)
```

Output is:

```
pressed :  Enter
```

I have a feeling though that this isn't what you were looking for. Let me know if I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: thanks for pointing the `__init__` method , to understand my goal better 
see the `example of usage` , simply if the user pressed ANY KEY in the keyboard this key name should be stored in the `pressedKey` variable , but your example only return the word (Enter)

Comment: Am happy to help. Can you accept this as the answer mate?

Comment: i think u misunderstood what i meant , your example only return the word (Enter) , but what i want is IF the user pressed ANY KEY in the keyboard this key name should be stored in the pressedKey variable automatic , so i can use it later like u see in my example of usage in the bottom of the question